# PHP Works but gives sql SYNTAX error

Tags: php, sql, error-handling, echo

I just wrote this bit of code which echo's out what it's supposed to but after the echo statement it give me the error-

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '' at line 1

why's this happening? how do i fix it?

```
<?php
$myclasses = explode(',', $_SESSION['classlist']);  
$theirclasses = explode(',', $user_info['classlist']);
$common_classes = array_intersect($myclasses, $theirclasses);

if (count($common_classes) > 0) {     

    foreach ($common_classes as $class) {
        $classes = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM classes WHERE class_id = ".$class) or die(mysql_error());
        while($currentRow = mysql_fetch_array($classes)){
        echo $currentRow['class_name'];
        }
    }  
}
else {
}

?>
```

Comment: Seems like there's an empty value in `$common_classes`.

Comment: if `$common_classes`, it should not enter the foreach loop, since there are checking for empty.

Comment: the main reason is the var $class empty. So some `",,"` in $user_info['classlist']

Comment: The answer given works. Simple error. Thanks so much guys. Excuse my lack of judgement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try wrapping your query with quote:

```
$classes = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM classes WHERE class_id = '".$class."'") or die(mysql_error());
```

or change your query altogether by using [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php). Because, mysql_* function are deprecated.

Comment: I can't for another 5 minutes!

Comment: haha, I'm aware of that. It's just reminder. I see your accept-rate are below 75%.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to assume that something is wrong in the $class variable when passed to the query. What I usually do in such scenarios is assign the SQL query to a string variable and dump it to test the entire query at once. Helps me find out SQL syntax errors or if there's any undesired characters.

```
<?php
$myclasses = explode(',', $_SESSION['classlist']);  
$theirclasses = explode(',', $user_info['classlist']);
$common_classes = array_intersect($myclasses, $theirclasses);

if (count($common_classes) > 0) {     

    foreach ($common_classes as $class) {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM classes WHERE class_id = '{$class}'" ; // use {} inside double quotes
        var_dump($sql); // check out the what the query becomes 
        $classes = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
        while($currentRow = mysql_fetch_array($classes)){
        echo $currentRow['class_name'];
        }
    }  
}
else {
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If $class is empty you'd get that error which would leave your query as `SELECT * FROM classes WHERE class_id =` which is not valid. Try quote it. If you quote it, at least you'll get `SELECT * FROM classes WHERE class_id = ''`

```
"SELECT * FROM classes WHERE class_id = '".$class."'";
```

Comment: Ugh, don't do that. This is an extremely hacky solution, and won't actually fix the problem, which is that $class isn't being properly checked. Before running any SQL, you should be validating that $class is a valid integer. Additionally, this will trigger a type conversion, which is a great way to have MySQL do work for no reason.